# Search entries in a radius using Postgresql, Bookshelf/Knex

Tags: javascript, postgresql, postgis, bookshelf.js, knex.js

My table has a Point column and stores a geom like (x,y)

I want to use Bookshelf to query for entries that are within a given radius. 
This is what my query looks like:

```
  getLocal: function(req, res, next) {
new Event()
  .query()
  .fetchAll()
  .then(function(events) {
    res.status(201).send(events);
  }).catch(function(err) {
    res.status(404).send(err);
  });
},
```

I tried it the bookshelf way:

```
.query( 'where', 'location_point', '<@', "point(circle '((37,127),50)"
```

I've tried the knex.raw way:

```
.query(knex.raw("SELECT * FROM events WHERE location_point <@ circle'((37,127),50)'")
```

I've tried it the Bookshelf.knex.raw way:

```
Bookshelf.knex.raw("SELECT * FROM events WHERE location_point <@ circle'((37,127),50)'")
```

So, I'm not really sure where to go from here.  I'm new at this and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have an working query when using it directly against the postgres database (using psql or pgadmin)? if so, knex.raw should return to you an object q little different. instead a list of events it should return to you something with a 'rows' attirbute, and this is your result. can you post what does it logs when you call it?

Comment: Yes, I've made a couple queries against the db and they are successful.  

I've been getting errors, with the knex.raw way I get:

    "error": "obj._knex[key].apply is not a function"

when I do it the Bookshelf.knex.raw way, I get:

"error": "Cannot read property 'knex' of undefined"

Comment: If it's a geolocation you're searching for then please use postgis and not in-built geometry.

Comment: Yes, I'ved tried that as well, but I'm having trouble inputting the command into bookshelf as a raw query:  
select * from events where st_within(location_point, st_buffer(st_point(127,37), 50))

Comment: if you are using PostGIS, the query to get the locations that are 50 m within the location in South Korea is `SELECT * FROM events WHERE ST_DWithin(location_point, ST_MakePoint(37, 127)::geography, 50.0)`